# JQUERY Help Needed!

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery-events: Click function
I have a webpage with search textbox and another textbox ( called textbox1).
When I search a name, I get a table in the same page with all relevant names in the NAME column with some additional information. This column can have 1, 2... 100 rows.. according to the search keyword. What I want to do is the following:
When I click on the cell of one of the results, I want its value to be copied into textbox1.

I tried the following but it can't seem to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("td").click(function () {
$(this).attr("id", "td1");
$("#textbox1").val(td1.innerHtml); // I also tried $("#textbox1").val(this.innerHtml);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Lilly, this is a community edited Q&A-list, not a bulletin board. You should consider this in your wording. How would you answer to the question "JQUERY Help Needed!"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it, it's just [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3aelement.innerHTML) (case-sensitive) instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("td").click(function () {
    this.id = "td1"; //no need for .attr() here either!
    $("#textbox1").val(this.innerHTML);
  });
});
```

Comment: I can't believe this was all about innerHTML being case sensitive!!! I've tried a million things!! Thanks a lot!! Though I do have another question, so this form with textbox1 exists in a pop up window that can be clicked while completing a form. After the search is over and the cell is clicked, I want the pop-up window to close, and the cell value to be filled in textbox1 which is in the form page. Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: sorry i meant another textbox which is in the original form page, I want to return to the form without refreshing it, so that the data that was being filled there won't be lost